Counting binary sequences where 1 stays ahead (Related to Ballot Theorem)
Fact. The number $a_n$ of $\{0,1\}$ sequences of length $n$ such that, for any prefix of the sequence, there are at least as many 1's as 0's, is ${n\choose \lceil{n/2\rceil}}$. First, I'll derive this.
Observe that $a_n$ is the number of $\{0,1\}$ sequences of length $n+1$ such that, for any prefix, there are strictly more 1's than 0's (bijection: add a "1" prefix to each string above). The Bertrand Ballot Theorem states that the number of sequences having this property with exactly $k$ ones is ${n+1\choose k}-2{n\choose k}$.
For brevity we'll consider the even case $a_{2n}$ only, but odd works as well. Iterating over all possible $k$, we find:
$$
a_{2n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\big[{2n+1\choose k}-2{2n\choose k}\big]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}{2n+1\choose k}-\sum_{\substack{k=0\\k\neq n}}^{2n}{2n\choose k}
=2^{n+1}/2-\big[2^n-{2n\choose n}\big]={2n\choose n}
$$
Question. Is there a smart bijection between the $2n$-length sequences enumerating $a_{2n}$ and the subsets of $\{1,\ldots, 2n\}$ of size $n$? Is there any nice combinatorial proof of the Fact above?

Let $w$ be a word of length $2n$ on $\{0,1\}$ such that every prefix of $w$ contains at least as many $1$'s as $0$'s. It can be represented by a path $P_w:\{0,\dots,2n\}\to \mathbb Z$ by setting $P_w(0)=0$ and $P_w(i+1)-P_w(i)=(-1)^{w_i+1}$ :

This is a well known bijection. This path must end at an even height $h$. Compute
$$m:=\max\{k: P_w(k)=h/2\}$$
For example,

Consider the path between $m$ and $2n$, reflect it vertically, and place it at the beginning of the trajectory (and shift the whole path so that it starts at $0$) :

The path $\widetilde{P}_w$ you obtain is always balanced (it starts and ends at the same height). If $m=2n$, then $\widetilde{P}_w=P_w$ (see the example of 1100 above: it is equivalent to say that $w$ is a Dyck word). Moreover, $P_w\mapsto \widetilde{P}_w$ is a bijection between positive paths and balanced paths (see Feller's An introduction to Probability Theory and its applications, III.10.7. in the 3rd edition). Now, consider the subset
$$S_w:=\{k, \widetilde{P}_w(k)-\widetilde{P}_w(k-1)=1\}\subset\{1,\dots,2n\}$$
Then $w\mapsto S_w$ is a bijection between words of length $2n$ satisfying your condition and subsets of size $n$ in $\{1,\dots,2n\}$. In case I wasn't clear, here are the examples for $w$, $P_w$, $\widetilde{P}_w$ and $S_w$ when $n=2$ :

Wa can describe the inverse of $w\mapsto S_w$. Let $S\subset \{1,\dots,2n\}$ with $\text{Card}(S)=n$. It is equivalent to consider the balanced word
$$w_0=\mathbb{1}_S(1)\mathbb{1}_S(2)\dots\mathbb{1}_S(2n-1)\mathbb{1}_S(2n)\in\{0,1\}^{2n}$$
where $\mathbb{1}_S(k)=1$ if $k\in S$ and $0$ otherwise. For example, for $n=3$,
$$S=\{1,3,4\}\implies w_0=101100$$
From $w_0$ we construct the path $\widetilde{P}:\{0,\dots,2n\}\to \mathbb Z$ defined by $\widetilde{P}(0)=0$ and
$$\widetilde{P}(k)=\sum_{i=1}(-1)^{w_0(i)+1}$$
For example,

Now for the tricky part, compute
$$\min\{k : \forall i, \widetilde{P}(k)\leqslant \widetilde{P}(i)\}$$
i.e. the leftmost (global) argmin. Flip the trajectory up to this point, and place it at the end of the path :

The resulting path $P$ is always positive. Assign to each of its step the symbol $1$ if it's a step up, and $0$ otherwise:

The word $w_S$ you obtain satisfies the condition we are interested in, and
$$w_{S_w}=w$$
so that both of these constructions define bijections that are the inverse of one another.

Thank you!!! Wanted to comment that $P_w$’s are similar to the construction of Dyck paths. For inverting $\tilde P_w\mapsto P_w$, we ”cut” at the first global minimum of $\tilde P_w$, right? Also should the reflection $P_w\mapsto \tilde P_w$ be horizontal, rather than vertical? I’m looking at your second example.

You're right! That's exactly what Feller designed as the inverse bijection. I added some details to my answer.

I almost sure the reflection is vertical, I'll check that tomorrow!

lol, I think you’re describing a left-right flip as vertical because you reflect across a vertical axis. If so, that’s my bad + thanks for more detail
